# Can not access object defined in controller from within directive with isolate scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a wizard component that has three directives.

Sliding Panel: normal scope

Sliding Panel Step: isolate scope

Sliding Panel Controls: isolate scope

My issue is that I cannot access an object defined on the page controller from within the Sliding Panel Step, which has isolate scope.

Within the page, I have this controller set up:

```html
<script>
function Controller($scope, yoSlidingPanelService) {

    //model to save data
    $scope.selections = {
        "list_name": '',
        "selectedCriteria": []
    }

    $scope.list = {
        "name": 'Example List'
    };

    $scope.isCriteriaSelected = false;

    $scope.test = yoSlidingPanelService.returnCopy();

    // toggle selection for a given fruit by name
    $scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(criteria) {
        var idx = $scope.selections.selectedCriteria.indexOf(criteria);
        // is currently selected
        if (idx > -1) {
            $scope.selections.selectedCriteria.splice(idx, 1);
        }
        // is newly selected
        else {
            $scope.selections.selectedCriteria.push(criteria);

        }

    };

    $scope.submit = function() {
        $scope.selections.list_name = $scope.list.name;
        console.log($scope.list.name + " saved!")
        console.log($scope.selections)
        //if ($scope.selections.selectedCriteria.length !== 0) {
            $scope.isCriteriaSelected = true;
        // }


    }
    $scope.numPerPage = 10;
    $scope.filter = {};
};
</script>
```

Then, I have the sliding panel along with the steps like so:

```
<div yo-sliding-panel-step step-id="second" step-handler='leaf()'> 
 <!-- stuff -->
 {{list.name}} <!-- CANNOT GET ACCESS TO THIS -->
</div>
```

My directive code is as follows:

```js
    // Sliding Panel
        yoBootstrap.directive('yoSlidingPanel', function() {
            var controller = ['$scope', function($scope) {
                //steps and stepHandlers
                $scope.steps = {};

                $scope.whatever = "something";
            }];

            return {
                restrict: 'AE',
                transclude: true,
                replace: true,
                template: yoSlidingPanelTemplate,
                controller: controller,
                scope: {
                    firstStep: '@'
                },
                link: function($scope, $element, $attributes, ctrl) {
                    ctrl.setAsFirstStep($scope.firstStep); // set the first step
                }
            };
        })
```

```js
// Sliding Panel "Step"
        .directive('yoSlidingPanelStep', function() {
            return {
                require: '^yoSlidingPanel',
                restrict: 'AE',
                transclude: true,
                replace: false,
                scope: {
                        stepId: '@',
                        stepHandler: '&'
                    },
                template: yoSlidingPanelStepTemplate,
                link: function($scope, $element, $attributes, yoSlidingPanelCtrl) {
                    $scope.currentStep = function() {
                        return yoSlidingPanelCtrl.getCurrentStep();
                    }
                    $scope.setCurrentStep = function(step) {
                        yoSlidingPanelCtrl.setCurrentStep(step);
                    }
                    // Populate "steps" array of objects with steps.
                    yoSlidingPanelCtrl.addStep($scope.stepId, $scope.stepHandler);

                    $scope.shareObject = function(obj){
                        yoSlidingPanelService.returnCopy(obj)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

I need isolate scope on my yo-sliding-panel-step because I want to make them reusable. That said, what is a good approach for me to get access to the scope object data from within the `yo-sliding-panel-step` ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Best approach is via 2-way binding which you are already doing. So bind that object as well as ytou do others. You are saying you want to make them reusable, and it you really want to then accessing a parent scope property directly, how does it help?

Comment: I guess, I was not clear enough. From one of the steps within the sliding panel, I want to ng-repeat over an object defined on the parent controller's scope. Let's say that if these were checkboxes, I want the selection to be persisted, so I can display that later after the modal containing the sliding panel is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My issue is that I cannot access an object defined on the page controller from within the Sliding Panel Step, which has isolate scope.

That precisely is the purpose of isolate scopes.

You can pass in to the directive whatever you want using an attribute and setting the binding. So instead of trying to pass in the full scope, create an option object (with all the relevant data) and pass it in, like you're already doing in a few places.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Shomz. So you mean I should define the object I want to access, on the `yo-sliding-panel` directive's controller?

Comment: You're welcome, did you manage to get it working? Yes, a controller scope object that you can pass in to the child directive.

Comment: I got to the point where I set up a two-way binding on an object `data : '='` I can also see the contents of data when I use `<div yo-sliding-panel-step step-id="yolo" options="{{data}}" blah blah >` How do I access {{data}} like so:  `<div yo-sliding-panel-step step-id="yolo"> {{data}}</div>` ?

Comment: Hmm, looks like you actually need: `<div yo-sliding-panel-step step-id="yolo" options="data" blah blah >` (no `{{}}`), and the scope definition as: `data: '=options'`. Then you'll have `scope.data` available based on the object passed in `options`.

Comment: your answer is correct for the problem I am facing.